# Connect REST api to add existing file to existing folder -- like ContentDocumentLink

Tags: rest, files, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I'm (successfully) uploading a file to the
`/connect/communities/{community}/files/users/me` endpoint.

I'm able to share that file with a specified user by creating a file share
`/connect/communities/{community}/files/{id}/file-shares` and that seems to work as well.

But what I'm unable to do is put that file in a folder. I was given some example Apex code for for the module/folder attachment:

```
Folder_Document_Link__c docLink = new 
Folder_Document_Link__c();  
    //for now uploading to root folder (null)       
   docLink.Content_Document_Id__c = conDoc;        
   docLink.Folder__c = currentFolderID;        
   docLink.File_Name__c = doc.ContentDocument.Title;       
     insert docLink;
```

But I can't figure out what the REST api equivalent for that is. The documentation reference doesn't have anything that seems like a FolderDocumentLink or ContentDocumentLink.

I've tried adding `parentFolderId` to the initial POST to `/connect/communities/{community}/files/users/me` but that seems to be ignored.

The documentation implies that I can add files to a folder by POST-ing to `/connect/folders/{folderId}/items` but it seems to be about initial upload, not about linking an existing file to that item.

I'm sure this is trivial to someone who knows their way around this API, but I'm relatively new and totally stumped. Thanks!

Comment: Update. using the https://workbench.developerforce.com and the REST explorer, I was able to find the /services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Folder_Document_Link__c endpoint which appears as if it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `/sobjects/Folder_Document_Link__c` works after all.

I just needed a pointer to the workbench rest explorer, as it's more comprehensive than the rest /connect API documentation.